# Traits and Their Usage

Tags: php, traits

As of late I have exploring and expanding my PHP skills into new territory and working on getting a better understanding of various design patterns. From a technical standpoint I understand traits and how they are useful but don't have the practical side down just yet. There is a piece of code that I was working on recently, and I am not sure if this is the best way of accomplishing what I want.

```
<?php namespace Acme\Traits;

trait TCities{

    /**
     * @var self
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $cityID;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var float
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $cityName;

    // more fields ----->>>



    /**
     * @return TCities
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!(self::$instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCityID(): int{

        return $this->cityID;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $cityID
     */
    public function setCityID(int $cityID){

        $this->cityID = $cityID;
    }

    // more methods ....
```

Since I have city data that can come from 3 different databases and used all over the system, this makes it easy access that data without having to know all of the fields from the various DBs.

Here is an example of how the trait gets used.

```
<?php namespace Acme\QueryLibs\MySql;

use Acme\Traits\TCities;

class SqlLocationQueries extends SqlQuery{

    use TCities;

    /**
     * SqlLocationQueries constructor.
     *
     * @param IDatabaseMySql $db
     */
    public function __construct(IDatabaseMySql $db){
        parent::__construct($db);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $cityID
     *
     * @return TCities
     */
    public function getCityData(int $cityID): TCities{

        $query = '  SELECT * 
                    FROM cities
                    WHERE id=? 
                    LIMIT 1 ';

        $params = [$cityID];

        self::setQuery($query);
        self::setParams($params);

        $result = self::readOne();

        if(empty($result)){
            LocationErrors::unknownCityByID($cityID);
        }

        $cityInst = TCities::getInstance();

        $cityInst->setCityID($result['cityID']);
        $cityInst->setCityName($result['name']);
        $cityInst->setLatitude($result['lat']);
        $cityInst->setLongitude($result['lon']);

        return $cityObj;
    }
```

As you can see, this method returns 'TCities'. It's very convenient but not sure if this is the right/good approach?

Then in a higher level method (This is a very simplistic use case but gets the point across)

```
$locationOrigin = new SqlLocationQueries($this->db);
$cityOriginData = $locationOrigin->getCityData($cityID);

echo 'Welcome to '.$cityOriginData->getCityName().'<br />';
echo 'Where the coordinates are '.$cityOriginData->getLatitude().' '.$cityOriginData->getLatitude().'<br />';
```

Is this a misuse of traits or a good use case from them? If it is a bad use case, what would be the more efficient and correct way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: You're using traits as if it were another class; 
$cityInst = TCities::getInstance();
Traits share their code with the class.
You could say: $this->setCityID($result['cityID']);

Comment: I think this comment sums it up: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#107548